# Combine rows with same value, and merge together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe from pandas, where i check how often a word appears in a text.

Now the word Year for example appears 40.000 times in a text, a little bit further below the same word Year also appears 12.000

I want to create a new dataframe, that removes the duplicates but adds the total count of year.

[image: Image of DF]

Comment: Why is the initial algorithm counting the first "Year" and the second "Year" separately. Are they written with different alphabets or something?

Comment: `df.groupby("id")["count"].sum()`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "count":    [ 43989, 21025, 15048, 13945, 12177],
    "lemma_string": [ 'jaar','mens','procent','tijd','jaar'],
    "id":  [ 'jaar','mens','procent','tijd','jaar'],
    
})
df=df.groupby(by='id').sum().reset_index()
df

id  count
0   jaar    56166
1   mens    21025
2   procent 15048
3   tijd    13945
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried to do that before, but doing that I end up with 300.000 rows with non words

Comment: and with this ? : df=df.groupby(by=['id,'lemma_string']).sum().reset_index()

Comment: what do you mean by non words ?

Comment: For example, the first 5 that i get back in return are : !,?,",n   ",",ianag  ",",prester  ",,,antisch ",-,uder

Comment: from nltk.corpus import words
"would" in words.words() you will be able to access to english words as a comparaison to delete undesired value

Comment: Undersired values are already taken out of the corpus right now.  I Lemmatized the words to prevent sparsity. Right now before narrowing down the dataset even further i wanted to clear out the duplicates and add them to one. So after that i can have a cut off length if words appear less than 30 times

Comment: if you do a groupby don't you have only one Year with the sum of all the count's year ?

Comment: no, nothing happens then

Comment: @LexKoster can you check my solution and test because as you can see it works I don t understand why it does nothing for you

Comment: This Indeed seems to work, I think it might be since my Frame is encoded, and other words seems to appear, Ill try to change it back to a normal string!

Comment: @LexKoster could you validate a solution or close the question please